# Raspberry pi hangs on boot

Tags: raspbian, usb, boot

My 512MB Raspberry Pi Model B Project Board
keeps getting stuck. It starts loading and gets stuck on
`USB port detected`.
I was waiting 10 minutes after this happened, and nothing changed.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide more info if you want help. Did you shutdown? How? Try looking at http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Power_.2F_Start-up

Comment: Unplug everything except the power and the video, see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Also note, a common indication that your power supply is underpowered is the rainbow square overlay on the monitor:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=82373

An underpowered supply is a common issue with regards to intermittent hangs and SD card corruption.

Comment: This is more like a comment, rather than an answer.

Comment: @recantha
 this is actually the answer in 99% of the cases where somebody asks a similar question.